# Unable to get paper colors from cups 2.0.1 using cups4j

Tags: cups, cups4j

I'm currently using Cups Version 1.2.4 for a print-application.
A mandatory feature is to read the paper color (White Paper, Blue Paper, ..). This is done by reading the mediaSupported tag with an old print library called jipsi.

The print-application is now going to be updated with a new CUPS version 2.0.2 and the print library Cups4j. 
If I try to read the paper color with the mediaSupported tag, the resultset outputs me papersizes like "iso_b4_250x352mm" instead of the paper colors I need to get.
The other data that Cups4j provides me for the printer also doesnt include the paper color.
[Cups4j printer information new Cups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHre.png)

If I use the old Cups Version 1.2.4 and cups4j, the mediaSupported tag contains the paper colors, that I need to get.
[Cups4j printer information old Cups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOH4P.png)

However the webinterface of the new Cups lists the paper colors that I need to access.
[Pic of Cups Webinterface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5kMg.png)

Now my question:
Is there any way to get the paper color, maybe by asking the IPP protocol directly?

Answer (score 0):

The IPP attribute [media-color-supported](https://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-ippprodprint10-20010212-5100.3.pdf) contains the media colors which are supported by the printer.

You can try this [C](https://github.com/sahilarora535/ipp-example/blob/master/get-printer-attributes.c) code to see whether the media-color-supported contains the required value. Or may be the values are stored in media-type-supported IPP attribute as per your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5kMg.png).

Though I am not familiar with cups4j, a similar class exists in [cups4j](https://github.com/harwey/cups4j/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/ethz/vppserver/ippclient/IppResponse.java) to get the printer attributes.